# Source for meaning of parasha break in Numbers 26:1

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, pinchas

Bamidbar 26:1 is written:

> וַיְהִי, אַחֲרֵי הַמַּגֵּפָה;  {פ}
>   וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֶל-מֹשֶׁה, וְאֶל אֶלְעָזָר בֶּן-אַהֲרֹן הַכֹּהֵן לֵאמֹר

The {פ} indicates a line break - in the middle of the pasuk.

It is my understanding that many modern commentators (e.g., http://www.vbm-torah.org/parsha.61/37pinchas.htm, http://www.tanach.org/bamidbar/pin/pins1.htm) understand that it's there because everyone who hasn't died yet (except Moses whose death is mentioned) will enter Israel.

What's the original source for this interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is found in [Sefer Chizkuni](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14034&st=&pgnum=156). It might date from earlier, since that work is based (in part) on the work of Rashi as well as other commentators and midrashim.